# Converting feature coefficients to probabilities scores for linear models

Tags: python, r, linear-regression

I have been looking into interpreting feature coefficient in a bounded capacity (0,1) as probability scores. So for example, if one has the following linear model for classification(*Logistic regression*),
then inverse logit should return one linear probability scores right as it is the inverse logs of odd ratio?

```
y<- c(1:3, 7, 6)
x1<- 1:5
x2<- c(20:25)
temp<-coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))
library('arm')
invlogit(temp[1]+temp[2])
```

However, in-case of linear regression for continuous value prediction,

```
coeff1/sum(coeff)
```

should return one probability scores right ? 
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `coeff1/sum(coeff)` cannot be a probability due to the fact that it can be bigger than 1. For instance:
`coeff1 = 1.`, `coeff2 = -.5`, then `coeff1/sum(coeff) = 2`. The interpretation of coefficients in linear regression is the derivative of the output variable with respect to the given predictor.